# which tablets run my Java application

Tags: java, arm, tablet

I am developing a `Java desktop application` in Netbeans. I run my application on PC but i may have to run it on ARM based tablets also. 
My application uses `JDK7` and `swingx` library. It also connects to `mysql` database so it uses mysql library too.
How can i know that my application can run on ARM based touch tablets? Is there any simulator for ARM or which tablet device should i buy for testing it?
Since i am Windows guy, i need your advice about these topics.

Comment: I guess it depends more on the running OS instead of which model. By default Android and iOS doesn't support java.

Comment: @Andi The Android userspace is java centric.

Comment: So? But I can't run a java jdk7 app on my android system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My application uses JDK7 and swingx library. It also connects to mysql database so it uses mysql library too.

The OS abstracts away low level hardware differences for these things, so the question is really *does the OS* support them.

There are actually several different, incompatible ARM architectures, I would guess the predominant one on tablets would be ARMv7 (as it is on phones), and the most common OS, Android.  Android uses Java but does not support the use of swing (it has its own GUI API), nor is there a MySQL implementation -- the de facto SQL is SQLite.

However, tablets running GNU/linux, of which there may be a few, will provide for Java, swing, and MySQL.

Comment: what do you think, is it a common thing running desktop applications on linux based tablets with arm? or should i better develop my application on android insead?

Comment: I think Android will be much much more common than linux (but this depends on context -- if you can install whatever you want on the tablets, there is a chance they will run linux if you void the warranty, etc, and replace Android).  If you structure the project correctly, you should be able to create Android and Swing frontends.  The SQLite db interface on Android is also, unfortunately, specific to Android, so you would then need two versions of that to a certain extent.